# как посмотреть собранную о minion-ах информацию?

Tags: saltstack

[имеется `salt-master` и ряд машин `salt-minion` (*minion*-ов)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SaltStack).

как посмотреть (в удобочитаемом виде) собранную о *minion*-ах информацию (особенно важно для случаев, когда *minion* недоступен)?

ведь она явно присутствует (в бинарном виде) в файлах `/var/cache/salt/master/minions/*/data.p`:

```
$ sudo cat /var/cache/salt/master/minions/minion001/data.p | hexdump -C | head
00000000  82 a6 70 69 6c 6c 61 72  80 a6 67 72 61 69 6e 73  |..pillar..grains|
00000010  de 00 3b ab 62 69 6f 73  76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e af  |..;.biosversion.|
00000020  43 43 43 4e 31 38 57 57  28 56 32 2e 30 34 29 a6  |CCCN18WW(V2.04).|
00000030  6b 65 72 6e 65 6c a5 4c  69 6e 75 78 a6 64 6f 6d  |kernel.Linux.dom|
00000040  61 69 6e a0 aa 7a 6d 71  76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e a5  |ain..zmqversion.|
00000050  34 2e 31 2e 34 ad 6b 65  72 6e 65 6c 72 65 6c 65  |4.1.4.kernelrele|
00000060  61 73 65 b0 34 2e 34 2e  30 2d 32 31 2d 67 65 6e  |ase.4.4.0-21-gen|
00000070  65 72 69 63 aa 70 79 74  68 6f 6e 70 61 74 68 9b  |eric.pythonpath.|
00000080  a8 2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69  6e b2 2f 75 73 72 2f 6c  |./usr/bin./usr/l|
00000090  69 62 2f 70 79 74 68 6f  6e 32 2e 37 da 00 26 2f  |ib/python2.7..&/|
```

Comment: это не вопросо-ответ. действительно не нашёл ответа ни у поисковиков, ни в по-диагонали просмотренной документации.

Comment: Вот тут что-то похожее. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19724347/2790048

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо, про такое я уже прочитал и в поисковиках и в документации. увы, это запросы к **работающим** *minion*-ам, а не выборка из кэша. с недоступными в данный момент *minion*-ами, увы, не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

посмотреть собранную о *minion*-е информацию можно с помощью [такой команды](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.cache.html#salt.runners.cache.grains):

```
$ sudo salt-run cache.grains имя-minion-а
```

пример вывода (первые десять строк):

```
имя-minion-а
    ----------
    SSDs:
    biosreleasedate:
        11/11/2015
    biosversion:
        CCCN18WW(V2.04)
    cpu_flags:
        - fpu
        - vme
```

---

обо всех *minion*-ах:

```
$ sudo salt-run cache.grains '*'
```

или даже без аргументов:

```
$ sudo salt-run cache.grains
```

---

информации довольно много:

```
$ sudo salt-run cache.grains имя-minion-а | wc -l
304
```

а главное, что требовалось — она берётся из кэша, без обращения к *minion*-ам, которые в этот момент могут быть и отключены.